# Symfony 4 authenticator with user activation system: modify login error message

Tags: symfony, symfony-security, symfony-4.4

I'm implementing a security system that, apart from credential, checks if user is *enabled*. To check if user is enabled after checking credentials is easy in my `AppAuthenticator`.

But the problem is I don't know how I can set *lastAuthenticationError* to show the message "The user is not activated" instead of "Invalid credentials".

I wasn't able to find source code or detailed documentation for these interfaces and classes.

Maybe I could add an attribute to `AppAuthenticator` like `$userActivated=true/false` and then check this value in `SecurityController` but still I would have the *Bad credentials* error, which could move to confussion in the login process.

So **the question is**: Can I modify *lastAuthenticationError* from `AppAuthenticator`?

This is my *guard* im `security.yaml`:

```
firewalls:
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\AppAuthenticator
```

And this is my `AppAuthenticator`:

```
    class AppAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
    {
        public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
        {
            $passwordOk = $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
            $userActivated = $user->getEnabled();
            //HERE I SHOULD BE ABLE TO SPECIFY AN ERROR MESSAGE TO DIFFER FROM BAD CREDENTIALS
            return $passwordOk and $userActivated;
        }
}
```

And this is `SecurityController.php`:

```
    class SecurityController extends AbstractController
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
         */
        public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
        {
            if ($this->getUser())
                return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');

            // get the login error if there is one
            $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
            // last username entered by the user
            $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

            return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
        }
    }
```